Definition of the space $\mathcal{S}'_h(\mathbb{R}^d)$
I am reading the book Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations by Bahouri, Chemin, and Danchin, in which they give the following definition:

We denote by $\mathcal{S}_h'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ the space of tempered distribution $u$ such that $$\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \|\theta(\lambda D)u\|_{L^\infty} = 0 \quad \text{for any } \theta \text{ in } \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d).$$

Here $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and I could not find where they defined $D$ but I assume it is an operator because in a footnote they say

We agree that if $f$ is a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with at most polynomial growth at infinity, then the operator $f(D)$ is defined by $f(D)a \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f\mathcal{F}a).$

$\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform.
They also give the following remark:

It is clear that whether or not a tempered distribution $u$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}_h'$ depends only on low frequencies. As a matter of fact, it is not hard to check that $u$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}_h'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ if and only if one can find some smooth compactly supported function $\theta$ satisfying the above equality and such that $\theta(0) \neq 0$.

Is there a name for this space? I couldn't find anything about it in other books. What exactly is this definition saying and how can we infer that only the low frequencies determine whether or not a tempered distribution belongs to it? In fact, how can we even speak of a particular frequency of a tempered distribution if these objects are not defined pointwise? Lastly, how does it make sense to take the $L^\infty$ norm of a distribution?

For the last part, sometimes authors will just voluntarily omit some details which are easy to track from the more important parts, but basically to make the definition rigorous you would add "$u$ such that $\theta(\lambda D)u$ is measurable for all $\lambda$/for $\lambda$ big enough and satisfies: (insert the formula)".
